# How to query list of values from a specific field in Elastic Search?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a following POJO:

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "person")
public class Person {

  @Id
  @JsonIgnore
  private String id;

   private String mainId;

  private String name;
}
```

How can I search from mainId field given a list of values (Example: ["1234", "567", "8910"]?

So far I am using this to code. but it gave me an exception when I tried to pass a list of too many values:

```
 BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    for (String mainId : mainIds) {
      queryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("mainId", mainId ));
    }
    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(queryBuilder).build();

    SearchHits<T> searchHits = this.operations.search(searchQuery, this.entityClass,
        this.operations.getIndexCoordinatesFor(this.entityClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the terms query to match a field with multiple values by passing an array or set of String.

```
 QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("mainId",mainId));
```

Do note the 's' in `termsQuery`.

Comment: is there a limit to number of list values when using this?

Comment: No, I don't think do